# Doubt related closed system and isolated system

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, adiabatic

In my book it is written that "A closed system with all adiabatic boundaries may not be isolated system."

But I have my own doubts. If closed system then no exchange of mass or material is taking place. And since walls are adiabatic so no heat is exchanged. So, these two condition indicate that the system is isolated. This my assumption.

Then is the book right or my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An isolated system exchanges no mass, heat, or work with its surroundings.  A closed system exchanges no mass with its surroundings.  An adiabatic closed system exchanges no mass or heat with its surroundings, but can exchange work.

Answer (score 0):

A box such as yours could be squeezed by external forces to reduce its volume.  Work is done on the box system by the external forces resulting in a an increase in internal energy of the system.